# I am trying to say "I was listening to the Lord of the Rings audiobook ..."

Tags: verb-usage

I am at a loss as to how to write "I was listening to the ..." because the translation keeps coming up as "Ich habe mir das Hörbuch Herr der Ringe angehört" however this loses doesn't seem correct because it's saying "I listened to" or "I have listened to" which feels wrong because "I was listening" describes a continuous action during a period in the past while "I listened" gives no such indication and merely states that it happened.

Comment: But you do realize that German uses other mechanisms to express continuity?

Comment: Related [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/50170/1696), to add something specific.

Comment: This isn't a question as is. The reason you're having trouble translating the sentence is because you only have the start of the sentence; Individual words and grammar constructs don't directly translate. Finish the sentence in english, and then ask how to express it in german, or otherwise change the question about how to express continuity in general (although that's a bit broad).

Comment: How do I say “Freundin” in English? Translations say “friend” but that seems wrong, because I do not want to say “Freund”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your comment on the other answer:

***What I am confused with*** though is how to correctly translate verbs that contain the ing endings.

It's okay to be confused. As *CallMeCody* pointed out in his correct answer, German does not encode the continous aspect into the verb form as English does. If you want to point out that aspect in German, you have to use other hints: a temporal conjuction as *als* or *während*, or a temporal adverb as *gerade*.

---

What I wanted to add, for your encouragement: you will encounter this problem not only with the continous aspect but with all aspects, modes, voices, tenses German has. The use of verbs in German is very different from English. What makes it hard and confusing is **things look alike, but they aren't.** Not at all.

- English *simple present* tense is about the present — while German *Präsens* tense is about everything but the past.
- English *present perfect* tense is about actions having a result in the present — while German *Perfekt* tense is about the past.
- English *simple past* tense is about the past — while German *Präteritum* tense is about an reported timeframe, which may be in the past but as well as valid in the future or in some fantasy world. (English does this too, but in German it's the almost exclusive use, apart from some common verbs.)
- English *past perfect* tense is about actions having a result in the past. — While German *Plusquamperfekt* has the same function for *Präteritum* German *Perfekt* has for *Präsens*.
- English *going-to-future* tense is about your future plans — German speakers simply use *Präsens* tense and time marker words instead.
- English *will-future* tense is about the future beyond your influence — while German *Futur I* tense is pretty similar in meaning, German speakers only use it sparsely. They use *Präsens* and time marker words instead.

This list is just about tenses (though not all of them!) and you already see how different they are used. The use of voices, moods, aspects is even more different.

So it's okay to be confused but don't be frustrated. You don't have to climb that hill in one day. No German ever did. It will come naturally to you as soon as you read/write/speak/listen to more German.

Comment: I find your wording *fantasy time a story plays in* at least confusing. *Als ich aus der Bahn stieg, war der Boden nass, weil es kurz vorher geregnet hatte* or *am 4. August 1914 erklärte Großbritannien dem Deutschen Reich den Krieg, weil dieses zuvor die belgische Neutralität verletzt hatte* - why would you call this **fantasy time**?

Comment: Because it's not the past. It's an arbitrary time frame your story plays in. *Das Planet-Express-Raumschiff **hob** kurz ab und **stürzte dann** auf die Straße vor dem Hangar. Später **stellte** sich heraus, dass Bender die L-Einheit verbogen **hatte**.* (old example) *Präteritum* has the same function for stories *Präsens* has for reality. *Plusquamperfekt* has the same function for stories *Perfekt* has for reality.

Comment: But in my two examples **it is** the real past, the second one even with a concrete date you can find in history books (history != story), so your wording does not cover all possible cases.

Comment: No. It's not the real past. It's the same events as in the real past, told from a storyteller perspective. The difference is crucial. Put both your examples into *Präsens* and *Perfekt*. See how the events feel "more real"? That's why authors sometimes decide against *Präteritum* in favour of *Präsens*. It feels more real.

Comment: Which term do you prefer instead of *fantasy time*? It cannot mention *past*.

Comment: You can call it past when you describe the linguistic term as *simple past tense* (include the word tense into the cursive part) to distinguish between them. Both *fantasy time* and *story* are confusing when it is a *report* about real events that occurred in the past.

Comment: Übrigens bezieht sich meine Kritik nur auf die in meinen Augen unglückliche Wortwahl an dieser einen Stelle, die Antwort insgesamt ist gut.

Comment: Wie gesagt, was schlägst du stattdessen vor? "report timeframe"?

Comment: Das wäre zwar immer noch nicht ideal, aber OK, zumal ich fürchte, dass jede bessere Variante umständlichere Formulierungen mit mehr Worten erfordern würden

Comment: thanks I feel that this is the core issue I often encounter when trying to formulate sentences in German. My mindset has never been geared to think of simple present  tense as everything but the past. Trying to formulate sentences that way just feels so alien.

Comment: Same as English tenses feel for German speakers. I occassionally write short stories in English and it drives me nuts. On each proofreading pass, I find Germanisms. I need at least ten passes in English to catch (almost) all the mistakes. At max two in German.

Answer (score 4):

But it is the correct translation.

If you want to stress out that something happened while you were doing something else you use "als" or "während".

"Ich habe mir das Herr der Ringe Hörbuch angehört, als es an der Tür klingelte."

"Ich habe mir das Herr der Ringe Hörbuch angehört, während meine Mutter einkaufen war."

Btw, "das Hörbuch Herr der Ringe" implies that "Herr der Ringe" is the name of the audiobook, just like in english "the audiobook Lord of the Rings".

Comment: what I am trying to say in full was:  I was listening to the audiobook "The Lord of the Rings" with my Bluetooth headset when you called, and I forgot to change the Bluetooth settings that will transfer the sound back to my phone during a call.

Comment: which looks like:

Comment: Ich habe das Hörbuch "The Lord of the Rings" mit meinem Bluetooth-Headset angehört, als Sie angerufen haben, und ich habe vergessen, die Bluetooth-Einstellungen zu ändern, mit denen der Ton während eines Telefonats wieder auf mein Telefon übertragen wird.

Comment: In the first example I'd use simple past, because it refers to a point in time. To stress the concurrency, one could use "gerade": "Ich hörte mir gerade das Hörbuch an, als es an der Tür klingelte". The second example is fine with present perfect, because it refers to time periods in both parts.

Comment: @user38737 As a general remark, you don't have to thrust everything into one sentence ;) Also, you might want to think about leaving out some technical details that the listener doesn't neccessarily care about: "Ich hörte mir gerade ein Hörbuch mit meinem Bluetooth-Headset an, als Sie anriefen. Da habe ich vergessen, die Audio-Ausgabe wieder zurück auf das Telefon zu stellen."

Comment: What I am confused with though is how to correctly translate verbs that contain the ing endings, because from what I can gather all I need is to add "als" or "während" and a description of another event, but what If I only want to say something like "I was listening to music". For this case I don't have a "as" something else was happening to add. or put another way how would could I tell if "Ich habe Musik gehört." was saying "I listened to music" or "I was listing to music."?

Comment: You say "Ich habe Musik gehört." That's just how it works in german.

Comment: When would you use "I listened to music." and when "I was listening to music."? Why is the difference so important to you? As a native german speaker I don't get what's the big deal ;)

Comment: @CallMeCody Simple past, "I listened to music", is used for past actions in general. The action may or may not have taken place at the point in time the conversation is about. It's also used for regular actions, habits etc. ("I listened to music (regularily), but when my CD player broke, I stopped"). On the other hand, past progressive, "I was listening to music", emphasizes that the action took place at the specific moment the conversation is about. It also emphasizes that the action lasted for a period of time, instead of just occuring at a single moment ("Verlaufsform").

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck: Deine grundsätzliche Bemerkung finde ich überflüssig. Die meisten Probleme lassen sich irgendwie umschiffen, aber meist sollen hier sprachliche Probleme geklärt, nicht vermieden werden.

Comment: I'm learning German myself but could the following work?:   "Als ich Musik gehört habe,..." Then it would be explicit from the first sentence that something else is going on while I was listening to music.

Answer (score 0):

» … feels wrong because "I was listening" describes a continuous action during a period in the past … «

“I was listening to the Lord of the Rings audiobook …”

You're looking for the temporal adverb "gerade" (often shortened to "grade" or "grad").

Ich hörte grad das Herr der Ringe Hörbuch, da schlug der Blitz ein.

Oder (vielleicht nicht ganz korrekt, aber gängig):

Ich war das Herr der Ringe Audiobuch am hören, da flog ein Vogel durchs Fenster.

Pattern is: Ich bin/war am suchen/arbeiten/schreiben.

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Am-Progressiv

Using objects of any case with the verb (like: ich war das Audiobuch am hören) doesn't ring quite correct (see note) to my ears but it is a very useful construction and it is frequently used. So I do use it.

Note: What students (Germans and others) aren't told is that many rules on grammar and pronunciation are too restrictive to account for the huge body of regional idioms, dialects, which is (or was) the true living matter that grammar has been extracted from.